# Get resolved ARM template after failed deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to get the ARM template as it was during runtime in the Azure Portal with the variables and parameters resolved?

Example below:

**AzureDeploy.json**

```
{
 "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
 "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "parameters": {
   "environment": {
     "type": "string",
     "defaultValue": "dev",
   },
   "storageSKU": {
     "type": "string",
     "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
     "allowedValues": [
       "Standard_LRS",
       "Standard_GRS",
       "Standard_RAGRS",
       "Standard_ZRS",
       "Premium_LRS",
       "Premium_ZRS",
       "Standard_GZRS",
       "Standard_RAGZRS"
     ]
   },
   "location": {
     "type": "string",
     "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
   }
 },
  "variables": {
    "storageAccountName": "[concat('companyname',parameters('environment'),'sa01'))]"
  },
 "resources": [
   {
     "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
     "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
     "name": "[variables('storageName')]",
     "location": "[parameters('location')]",
     "sku": {
       "name": "[parameters('storageSKU')]"
     },
     "kind": "StorageV2",
     "properties": {
       "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

**AzureDeploy.parameters.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "environment": {
      "value": "dev"
    }
  }
}
```

If this deployment was to fail on something such as the name or the SKU, would I be able to access the portal or somehow see how these values were resolved when the script was ran?

The deployment happens in a CD pipeline in AzureDevops and I have control of the variable groups etc. so I know what is being passed in but not how it resolves. In a more complex template, I have an error claiming an Id is not set on a Logic App API connection but I cannot tell if the error is due to the variable I am using in the concat function or if the value is genuinely incorrect (resolving okay according to data passed in).

If anyone is familiar with troubleshooting these through the deployments blade in Azure then you may have some tips on how to see a more detailed view.

Thanks,

**Edit:**

The code below triggers Intellisense in Visual Studio 2019 but has been confirmed working during deployment. No warnings in VS Code as per comments. Majority of code omitted for brevity.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "environment": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "dev"
        },
        "increment": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "01"
        },
        "keyvaultName": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "randomKeyVaultName",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "Keyvault Name for deployment"
          }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "uniqueKeyVaultName": "[parameters('keyvaultName')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
          "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
          "name": "[concat(variables('uniqueKeyVaultName'), '/407045A0-1B78-47B5-9090-59C0AE9A96F6')]",
          "location": "northeurope",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'cosmosdb_linkedtemplate')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "contentType": "Graph",
            "value": "[concat('{''D'': ''DatabaseName'', ''U'': ''https://randomcosmosdb-',parameters('environment'),'-cdb-',parameters('increment'),'.documents.azure.com'', ''C'': ''CollectionName'', ''K'': ''',reference('cosmosdb_linkedtemplate').outputs.accountKey.value,'''}')]",
            "attributes": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

[image: Visual Studio Version]

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a template I took from Microsoft docs for an example and just noticed typo in "variables('storageName')" which should be "variables('storageAccountName')". I'm just looking for something more detailed than the standard output log generated during the deployment. Cheers

Comment: From the deployment page you can see what the inputs to the arm template were. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not quite, I know what the inputs are because I set them in the pipeline although I didn't notice you could see that from this blade so thank you for that. I want to see what the script would look like if you could imagine it hardcoded with the inputs e.g. "storageAccountName": "[concat('companyname',parameters('environment'),'sa01'))]" would become "storageAccountName": "fakecompanydevsa01"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the evaluated template there are a few things you can do to get it without deploying:

1) call the /validate api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/validate -- but you need to use an older apiVersion at the moment (e.g. 2017-05-01)... the response will contain the fully evaluated template.  If you have an older version of PowerShell or the CLI, you can see the response from the rest API by using the -debug switch.  But keep in mind, the more recent versions of PS/CLI will use a newer apiVersion and those don't return the full template (at this time).

2) The /whatif api will also return evaluated JSON but there's a bit more to wade through if all you're after is the evaluated template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-deploy-what-if

Tha help?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet because I got over my hump but looking at the links and other posts this does look to be the answer. The issue I was having was to do with escaping single quotes when using concat and the IDE kept giving red squiggles. As it turns out they are not actual errors and the string concatenates fine if you ignore them. I'll definitely use this in future though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?  And could you send me a sample that generated the squiggly? (that sounds like a bug (if it's in VS Code))

Comment: I've taken a snippet of the offending section in the template and omitted the rest of the resources for you to take a look. I use VS 2019 Community version 16.5.4, and I have just tested the same in VS Code version 1.44.2 and it is fine (no intellisense warnings). I am using the official Microsoft Azure Resource Manager extension in VS Code. I'll post the details with the  code in the original question. Thanks

Comment: ah... got it.  VS Code is a little more "up to date" than VS+ ... I'll fwd to our VS folks.